# Django. Получить связанные объекты

Tags: python-3.x, django

Имеется вот такого вида модель

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class SubCategory(models.Model):
    parent_id = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='sub_parent_id')
    sub_cat_title = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class Item(models.Model):
    parent_id = models.ForeignKey(SubCategory, related_name='item_parent_id')
    item_title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

Как за **1 запрос** к БД получить все связанные записи объекта Category? Насколько я понимаю, это можно сделать как-то через ***prefetch_related***, но не могу разобраться, как именно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**select_related()** следует пользоваться, если вам необходимо получить все связные объекты (чтобы не делать доп. запросы). 
 
Этот метод работает только со связями один-к-одному (*OneToOne*), один-ко-многим и когда нужно получить один объект.

Пример: `Item.objects.select_related().all()`

**prefetch_related()** этим методом мы получаем также все связанные объекты, но уже работает со всеми видами связей. Т.к. запросив данные, он делает их объединение на уровне Python'а.

Пример: `Item.objects.prefetch_related().all()`

В вашем случае, лучше использовать **select_related('parent_id')**, а также почитать об этих методах подробнее в документации Django, раздел `QuerySet API`.

Comment: а нет ли какого-нибудь иного способа получить все связанные объекты? Мне нужно организовать древовидное меню из связанных моделей. Без использования MPTT и сторонних библиотек.

Comment: @moffire, Лично я такой же подход использовал (использовал метод select_related() ) в своих проектах для организации древовидного меню и "хлебных крошек", чтобы не использовать MPTT.

Comment: ну вот смотрите, согласно вашему совету я использую Item.objects.select_related('parent_id'). Получаю QuerySet. А как потом мне достать оттуда всю информацию из связанных моделей и передать все в шаблон? Туплю 3й день, раздел в доке перечитал неоднократно, но не могу понять логическую цепочку. Может остались конкретные примеры из того, что делали сами подобным способом?

Comment: Во views.py:
`context = {}`

`context['objects'] = Item.objects.select_related('parent_id')`

#Передаете в шаблон данные

# В шаблоне:
`{% for object in objects %}`
`{{object.parent_id.sub_cat_title.title}}`
`{% endfor %}`

Comment: Естественно вам придётся небольшую логику сделать в шаблоне.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то это должно помочь:

```
Item.objects.select_related().all()
```

Запрос выполнится 1 раз с 2-мя join-ами

Источник: https://djbook.ru/rel1.4/ref/models/querysets.html