# Как создать форму из двух связанных моделей?

Tags: python, django, forms, views

Я новичок в django, поэтому прошу помочь с проблемой.
Есть класс Курсов, собсвенно вот он:

```
class Course(models.Model, HitCountMixin):
    STATUS_CHOICES = ((1, u'На модерации'),
                      (2, u'Отклонена'),
                      (3, u'Включена'))
    title = models.CharField(u'Заголовок', max_length=250)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title', unique=True, max_length=255)
    category = models.ForeignKey(CourseCategory,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(u'Картинка', upload_to=user_courses_directory_path,
                              blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(u'Описание', blank=True, default='')
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        u'Цена', blank=True, default=0)
    status = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=1)
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    likes = ArrayField(models.IntegerField(blank=True), blank=True, null=True)
    dislikes = ArrayField(models.IntegerField(blank=True), blank=True, null=True)

    hit_count_generic = GenericRelation(
        HitCount, object_id_field='object_pk',
        related_query_name='hit_count_generic_relation')

    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = CourseManager()
```

А теперь класс Видеокурсов которые относятся к Курсам

```
class CourseVideo(models.Model, HitCountMixin):
        """Model for course videos"""
        title = models.CharField(u'Заголовок', max_length=250)
        course = models.ForeignKey(Course,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        price = models.PositiveIntegerField(
            u'Цена', blank=True, default=0)
        is_published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        position = models.PositiveIntegerField(u'Позиция', default=1)
        is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

        likes = ArrayField(models.IntegerField(blank=True), null=True)
        dislikes = ArrayField(models.IntegerField(blank=True), null=True)

        image = models.ImageField(u'Картинка', upload_to=user_course_video_directory_path, null=True)
        preview_video = models.FileField(
            upload_to=user_course_video_directory_path, blank=True, null=True)
        image = models.ImageField(u'Картинка', upload_to=user_directory_path,
                                  blank=True, null=True)
        file = models.FileField(
            upload_to=user_course_video_directory_path)

        objects = CourseVideoManager()
```

Видеокурсы это видеоэлементы Курса и мне нужно создать форму где я могу создать Курс и добавить видео на одной и той же странице.
Пожалуйста, помогите кто сможет. Спасибо заранее!!!
СОС СОС СОС

Comment: Какая версия питона?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/842937/django-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%8B